# A way to update CartoDB's info window in real time?

Tags: carto

With mapbox, I'm able to populate a JS array and draw a layer in realtime. I'm wondering if, once I pulled a map with createVis in cartodb, I can populate the infowindow with data per shape.

For example I'm pulling (from the PHP) the latest statistics per shape. And I draw/render the cartodb, and I want, on infowindow open, to show that information (so if I have shape id 60, I want corresponding statistics from my local mysql database). Is this possible? Or do I need to store all the data into cartodb and then redraw the map?

Answer (score 1):

With CartoDB.js you can change the infowindow of any layer to meet your requirements, like having custom javascript on it to make further calls to CartoDB SQL API  ([example here](http://bl.ocks.org/javisantana/6451830)).

Comment: But all data needs to come FROM cartodb's database right? SO I have to send data there, then redraw the map, rather than applying data directly to the map in real time.

Comment: you can get the data wherever you want to, that example uses CartoDB SQL API but you can fetch data from any other source, it's pure javascript, up to you :) *BUT* if you need the data to drive your map, since it's rendered by CartoDB it needs to be stored on a table, of course.